# Mixpanel - Track All Links and get the link value

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

Rather than setting up IDs and setting up a separate tracking event for each link (my code changes often), I was wondering if there was a way I could set Mixpanel up to track all links (and buttons even) and get the value of the link `eg "/readmore"` so that I don't have to code for each possibility.

I looked at the Mixpanel Javascript API reference and read about mixpanel.track_links which seems to be in the right direction for what I am looking for, but i have to specify a `"name"` upfront which would register all events with the same name?

Here's some example code from the mixpanel api reference:

```
// with properties function
mixpanel.track_links
("#footer", "Footer link", function(ele) { return { type: $(ele).attr('type')}});
```

I'd like to replace `"#footer"` with say `"a"` i.e all links, and then for the value of the link to be returned.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 12):

From what I've seen, the mixpanel selector engine is quite limited and it appears that multiple selector syntax is not supported. However, if you give all your `button` and `anchor` elements a class, you will be able to target them with one call to `track_links` (with the added advantage that you can easily exclude elements you don't want to track):

```
mixpanel.track_links(".mixpanel-tracked", "Link clicked", function(ele) { 
    return { type: $(ele).attr('type') } 
});
```

If you can't use a class for whatever reason, you could target multiple elements by naming your function and passing a reference to it to separate calls to the `track_links` function:

```
var getLinkData = function(ele) { 
    return { type: $(ele).attr('type') } 
}

mixpanel.track_links('a', 'Link clicked', getLinkData);
mixpanel.track_links('input', 'Link clicked', getLinkData);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this.

Wrap your links in a `<div id="nav"`>

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="/pricing">Pricing</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    mixpanel.track_links("#nav a", "click nav link", {
        "referrer": document.referrer
    });
</script>
```

> This will send a "click nav link" event (with a 'referrer' property)
>   each time a user clicks on a navigation link. It's important to note
>   that the links matched by the CSS selector must exist on the page at
>   the time the mixpanel.track_links call is made, or it will not bind
>   correctly.
>
> One special note here is that **nested CSS selectors will not work** with
>   the default Mixpanel methods mixpanel.track_links above and
>   mixpanel.track_forms below. In order to utilize nested selectors or
>   manually recreate the behavior of these methods, you should utilize
>   code which sends an event to Mixpanel when a CSS element is interacted
>   with which includes a callback.

See the [Mixpanel Docs for more info](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/javascript)